# angularjs get value's value of the select tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select ng-model="data.person">
              <option value="1" selected="">1 pax</option>
              <option value="2">2 pax</option>
            </select>
```

Above ng-model returned 1 pax but how to get 1, which is the val's value?

Note : I saw some did it with multiple object in json array and with ng-repeat, but I believe there is a simpler way to do it.

Comment: attribute name for the first option should be `value` not `val`.

Comment: I noticed you edited your question based on @VinayK's comment. Did that not solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
        <select ng-model="data.person">
            <option value="1" selected="">1 pax</option>
            <option value="2">2 pax</option>
        </select>
    <br/>
    <p>Values is {{ data.person }} </p>
</div>
```

Here you have a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gumarelo/v1kxq3me/)